# Simple file selector/manager editor , mootools or Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, file-upload, editor, mootools

Is there any simple file manager that will let me browse server and select a file , no full blown file editors like elfinder etc, something very plain, all I need is,  let user browse his server and select file from folder. Even simple popup box with list of files from specific folder would do the job.
Thank you.

Comment: _let user browse his server and select file from folder_ or let user browse his system(client) & select the file from folder.?

Answer (score 0):

This one by Christoph Pojer is pretty awesome!

http://mootools.net/forge/p/mootools_filemanager

FileManager uses the FancyUpload3 script that is soon to be released for good-looking file uploads.

And, it can be easily integrated with TinyMCE as well.

Comment: thank you but already tested that one. it is again full blown manager like elfinder